# predict function error - wrong environment type?

Tags: r, environment, predict

I have a question regarding the predict function in R. 
I'm trying to validate a binomial GLM model, and in model interpretation, I run across the following error (to which I haven't found any clear answer online)

```
#Model interpretation
range(Data$col1)

MyData <- expand.grid(col1 = seq(from = -85.97, 
                                    to = 510.06, 
                                    length = 25),
                  Position = levels(Data$col1))


P1          <- predict(M1, newdata = MyData, se = TRUE, type = "link")
MyData$Pi   <- exp(P1$fit) / (1 + exp(P1$fit))
MyData$SeUp <- exp(P1$fit + 1.96*P1$se.fit) / (1 + exp(P1$fit + 
1.96*P1$se.fit))
MyData$SeLo <- exp(P1$fit - 1.96*P1$se.fit) / (1 + exp(P1$fit - 
1.96*P1$se.fit))
MyData
```

The error is:

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = 
object$xlevels) : 
invalid type (environment) for variable 'Position'
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you so much

Comment: we can't see what `M1` is, let alone `Data$col1`

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that `col1` is not actually a factor. That means `levels(Data$col1)` returns `NULL` and `MyData` only has 1 column for what you call `col1` but `Position` is not there. Then when doing prediction, R does not find `Position` in the data frame and looks for it in the global environment, thus finding the base function `?Position`. Instead of `levels` you might consider using `Position = sort(unique(Data$col1))`.